# Image in my extension is blocked by browser

Tags: image, google-chrome-extension, content-script, imageblocks

I am developing chrome extension which are injecting image in page using contentScript.js (using manifest version 3). But the image is not loaded only its title is showing, After I inspect the image URL and opened in a new tab it shows up the following errer:
{
kmifipphflgbabnneonimcpamgkkilkn is blocked
This page has been blocked by Microsoft Edge
}
How to solve this issue, its security layer or anything else;

The code and screenshots are below.

````
 const newVedioLoaded = ()=>{
        const bookmarkBtnExists = document.getElementsByClassName("bookmark-btn")[0];
        console.log(bookmarkBtnExists)
        if(!bookmarkBtnExists){
            bookmarkBtn = document.createElement('img');
            bookmarkBtn.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("Assets/bookmark.png");
            bookmarkBtn.className = 'ytp-button ' + 'bookmark-btn';
            bookmarkBtn.title = 'Click to book mark the current timestamp'
            youtubeLeftcontrol = document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-left-controls')[0];
            youtubePlayer = document.getElementsByClassName('vedio-stream')[0];
            youtubeLeftcontrol.appendChild(bookmarkBtn)
        }
        console.log(bookmarkBtn);[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJzfE.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAHBH.jpg)
    }

```[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxNDJ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2xev.jpg)
````

Comment: I think you should add that resource in "web_accessible_resources" section of your manifest file

Comment: @Robbi Yes, thanks you that works for me, its start working when I add the resources in web_accessible_resources porperly.